# Self Filtering Table with DAX in Tabular Model very slow

Tags: ssas, dax, tabular, ssas-tabular

I have a Fact-Table containing order positions and the corresponding order number. It has about 250 mio rows.

My Goal is to create a measure which can be used to answer the following question: What's the total revenue of all orders containing product xyz.

I added a table containing all distinct article numbers called Orderfilter with just one column OrderFilter[ArticleNr]. This table shall be used to filter the orders table. This table is not related to the orders table.

Based on this setup I created following measure.

```
Orderfilter Sum sales:=SUMX(
CALCULATETABLE (
    Orders;
    FILTER (
        Orders;
        CONTAINS (
            CALCULATETABLE (
                VALUES(Orders[OrderNr]);
                FILTER (
                    Orders;
                    CONTAINS (
                        VALUES ( Orderfilter[ArticleNr] );   
                        Orderfilter[ArticleNr];
                        Orders[ArticleNr]
                    )
                )
            ); 
            Orders[OrderNr];
            Orders[OrderNr]
        )
    )
);
Orders[Salesamount]
)
```

This calculation by itself seems to be working, but it is very slow. When i try to use it in Excel putting hierarchies into the rows it gets timed out.

Is there any possiblity tuning this query?

Regards,
Henning Lange

**Update: Desired Result Tables (really don't know how to add tables here...)**

The Orders table. If i filter for ArticleNr=2 i want to keep the "<- Keep"-rows.

```
|OrderNr     |ArticleNr  |    
|1           |1          |   <- Keep    
|1           |***2***    |   <- Keep    
|2           |1          |    
|2           |3          |    
|3           |***2***    |   <- Keep
```

Comment: Why don't you create the relationship between both tables? it would be more performant than use **CONTAINS** function in a **FILTER**. Explicit relationships are always faster than filters.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the fast response. I think a relationship would not help me with this problem. If i create a relationship between those tables i would relate on Orders[ArticleNr] to Orderfilter[ArticleNr]. This way i would filter the Orders table based on ArticleNr. But that is not what I want to achieve. I want to filter the Orders table based on OrderNr.
"What are the sales of all orders containing articles x,y or z?" With your proposal i could answer the question "What are the sales of the articles x,y or z?". Or am i wrong in this assumption?

Comment: I'd handle it at the source, i.e, creating a common column in the Orders and the Orderfilter tables. Edit your question to include sample data and expected result.

Comment: I added a "table" to the question.

Comment: In that example the first row is included because the OrderNr value is the same as the second row which **does** have the selected ArticleNr (Number 2), right? Is that the rule to determine the filtered rows?

Comment: Hi, yes that is the desired behaviour. I want to get all the orders containing that articleNr.

Comment: Check my answer. Hope It helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach will work only if you select one `ArticleNr`. Since I am using `MAX()` function to determine what is the selected value in the filter it will return the maximum selected `ArticleNr` always.

Consider this sample data:

**Orders Table**

```
OrderNr  ArticleNr  Revenue
   1         1        100
   1         2        200
   2         1         50
   2         3         70
   3         2        300
   3         4        200
   4         1         50
```

**Articles**

```
ArticleNr
   1
   2
   3
```

Create a measure to determine the rows:

```
Rows :=
SUMX ( FILTER ( Orders, [ArticleNr] = MAX ( Articles[ArticleNr] ) ), 1 )
```

Now using the `Rows` measure you can get the `Sum Sales`:

```
Sum Sales :=
SUMX (
    FILTER ( Orders, SUMX ( ALLEXCEPT ( Orders, Orders[OrderNr] ), [Rows] ) = 1 ),
    [Revenue]
)
```

This is a Pivot Table in Power Pivot.

[image]

Comment: Hi, this works great! I am amazed how much effort you spent into this question. In the end i was not very happy with the opportunity to filter only on one ArticleNr. I found another solution which works with multiple ArticleNrs here: http://blog.gbrueckl.at/2012/05/resolving-many-to-many-relationships-leveraging-dax-cross-table-filtering/

Answer (score 0):

If it is only slow when you use hierarchies in Excel, then the hierarchies are the problem. Probably it is unnatural. Excel sends down MDX queries to SSAS no matter what engine is used(tabular/multidim). And when it comes to unnatural hierarchies things goes wrong.

Try to build up natural hierarchy and check it then.
Take Date dim as an example.
You have Date, Month, Year. If you simply put January - December into the Month column, it wont be unique. Try explicitly specifing hierarhy members. Like in this case put also the year into the month column, like January - 2016, etc. Therefore each month will be unique, and the engine will no which member to take when you do drill-downs.